# How to get datetime difference in a day with joda time in java

Tags: java, vaadin, jodatime

Am trying to get datetime difference with joda time (ie startdate -2014-02-26 and enddate-2014-02-26) for a day but i **keep on getting a blank table**.When i change to startdate -2014-02-26 and enddate-2014-02-27 data gets displayed. below is sample code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 

Date todaydate = new Date();
DateTime jodaToday = new DateTime(todaydate);

String datefrom = sdf.format(jodaToday.toDate());
String dateto = sdf.format(jodaToday.plusDays(1).toDate());
```

and my query looks like below.

```
ProductTable.setContainerDataSource(storeData(
    "SELECT * FROM sales where sale_time BETWEEN '"
    + datefrom + "' AND  '" + dateto + " ' ORDER BY sale_time DESC"
));
```

What could i be missing ?

NOTE: When i do a test with the below query i get data

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE sale_time BETWEEN
'2014-02-26 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-26 23:59:59' ORDER BY sale_time DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the type of your table column `DATE` or `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`)? If the former, then this is odd. If the latter and the values are differ in time, then you should use the second approach.

Comment: Do you have "data from the future"?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the table column is TIMESTAMP. Which second approach ?

Comment: @maszter yes i have.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is more about understanding the `BETWEEN` SQL statement. In simple words, `BETWEEN` can be explained as:

```
FOO BETWEEN A AND B
```

Which is equivalent to

```
FOO >= A AND FOO <= B
```

With this in mind, if you have `sale_time >= '2014-02-26' AND sale_time <= '2014-02-26'`, it will be understood by your database engine as `sale_time >= '2014-02-26 00:00:00' AND sale_time <= '2014-02-26 00:00:00'`. So, the database engine won't be able to find a row which `sale_time` value is `'2014-02-26 05:32:16'` or similar.

After understanding this, then you're able to understand why setting the second parameter of your between works when you add one day to today. The SQL statement would be:

```
sale_time BETWEEN '2014-02-26' AND '2014-02-27'
```

Which can be understood as:

```
sale_time >= '2014-02-26 00:00:00' AND sale_time <= '2014-02-27 00:00:00'
```

I don't know vaadin but you should use a method where you will send these `String`s as parameters rather than concatenating them to generate the query to execute. Note that if you do this more and more your application is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

Data from midnight to midnight:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

DateTime from = new DateTime(2014, 2, 26, 0, 0).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime to = from.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusSeconds(1);

String datefrom = sdf.format(from.toDate());
String dateto = sdf.format(to.toDate());
```

**EDIT**

Maybe the extra space is the problem:

```
...dateto + " ' ORDER BY...
             ^
```

Comment: have tried as above but i still get a blank page. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss still not shown for a day, but i like how you have coded it. see how i tested it SELECT * FROM sales where sale_time BETWEEN '2014-02-26 00:00:00' AND  '2014-02-26 23:59:59' ORDER BY sale_time DESC;

Comment: @pmaingi Edited to 23:59:59

Comment: @pmaingi I have changed the date to 2014-02-26.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit difficult to give an answer without the Table and data,

1. Set break point to the "datefrom" and check whether correctly set "datefrom" and "dateto".
2. Check the Table column DATE or TIMESTAMP.
3. Check data is available in table match your criteria.
4. Get this query and set hard-coded "datefrom" and "dateto" and execute as a SQL query in your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the solution that worked. Note added timestamp(23:59:59) in bold.

```
  " AND sale_time >= '"+sdf.format(fromdate.getValue())+"' AND sale_time <=  '"+sdf.format(Todate.getValue())**+"  23:59:59'"**;
```